# A statistical robust least-squares problem

Tags: probability, convex-optimization, least-squares, expected-value, random-matrices

> Consider the following statistical robust least-squares problem
>
> $$\text{minimize } \mathbb E \|Ax - b\|_2^2$$
>
> where $A = \bar A + U$, where $\bar A$ is the mean of $A$ and $U$ is a zero-mean random matrix. We can express the objective as $$\mathbb E \|Ax - b\|_2^2 = (\bar Ax-b)^T(\bar Ax - b) + \mathbb E [x^TU^Tux]$$

Why can we can express the objective as $E ||Ax - b||_2^2 = (\bar Ax-b)^T(\bar Ax - b) + E[x^TU^TUx]$

Isn't $E ||Ax - b||_2^2 = E(\bar Ax-b)^T(\bar Ax - b) + 2E(\bar A x - b) +  E[x^TU^TUx]$?

Answer (score 1):

Note that
\begin{align*}
 & \mathbb E \| Ax - b \|_2^2 \\ =& \mathbb E \left[ [(\bar A x - b )^T + (U x)^T][(\bar Ax - b) + (Ux)] \right] \\
=& \mathbb E[(\bar Ax - b)^T(\bar A x - b)] + \mathbb E[(\bar Ax - b)^T(Ux)] + \mathbb E[(\bar Ax - b) (Ux)^T] + \mathbb E[(Ux)^T(Ux)] \\
=& (\bar A x - b)^T (\bar A x -b) + (\bar A x - b)^T \mathbb E[Ux] + (\bar A x - b) \mathbb E[(Ux)^T] + \mathbb E[x^T U^T U x]
\end{align*}
where the last step is justified because $\bar A$, $b$, and $x$ are deterministic and behave like constants with respect to expectations. Since $U$ has mean $0$, the middle terms vanish.

The issues with your alternative formulation are (1) we don't need an expectation on the leftmost term because it's not random, and (2) the $Ux$ terms seem to have been dropped from the middle components.

Comment: it was probably assumed that $\mathbb{E}(U)=0$

Comment: @LinAlg It was in the problem text: "...where $\bar A$ is the mean of $A$ and $U$ is a zero-mean random matrix."

Comment: Very good! So that explains why "the $Ux$ terms seem to have been dropped from the middle components."

Comment: Ah, now I understand what you mean. What I meant to indicate with my comment was that those terms were omitted from the proposed formula (effectively treating them as 1) rather than zeroed out.